# When Lebesgue measure of $A$ is equal to Lebesgue measure of $TA$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear transformation.

Let $T A = \{T x\;|\;x \in A\}$ be the image of a measurable set $A$. I have the following question:

Under what conditions on $A$ and $T$ is it true that the Lebesgue measure $m(A)$ of $A$ is the same as the Lebesgue
measure $m(T A)$ of $TA$.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52161/169852

Comment: If the determinant equals $1$.

Comment: @gary Kindly mention some reference.

Comment: @Tensor_Product: Please see link above my post, it describes the general result. Please let me know if this is not enough.

Comment: Thank you both of  you.  Reference: Aliprantis and Burkinshaw's Principles of Real Analysis, Third Edition, Lemma 40.4 pp 389-390.

Comment: Tiny nit:  If the absolute value of the determinant equals $1$.  This is of course implied by  the link above but contradicted by gary's comment.

Comment: Note also that the result holds if $m(A) = 0$, regardless of the determinant of $T$.